# Earnshaw Theorem for ionic solids

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, physical-chemistry, stability

Is a single molecule of sodium chloride (say) or a cluster of molecules of NaCl unstable, although macroscopically NaCl is in fact, stable?
How can I reason this based on [Earnshaw's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem)?

Comment: Earnshaw's theorem is valid for classical point particles. However, $\text{Na}^+$ and $\text{Cl}^-$ ions are diffuse quantum objects, so Earnshaw's theorem is not necessarily applicable. However, you might be able to apply it to a gas of $\text{Na}^+$ and $\text{Cl}^-$ ions to qualitatively suggest that it's unstable, and thus should collapse (ie, condense) to form the ionic solid. In the gas phase, the classical point-particle approximation is probably more valid than in the solid phase.

Answer (score 1):

There is a related question in [Is NaCl vapour plasma?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43650/is-nacl-vapour-plasma). According to my answer to that question [this paper](http://jcp.aip.org/resource/1/jcpsa6/v104/i17/p6724_s1?isAuthorized=no) states that sodium chloride vapour contains NaCl molecules, dimers and indeed polymers, so these are all stable. However when I've just tried the link I got an error from the AIP server. Some Googling found a similar and possibly the same paper [here](http://connection.ebscohost.com/c/articles/7618887/sodium-chloride-vapor-very-high-temperatures-linear-polymers-are-important).